# Flutter's ListView needs clickable elements, and leading images don't show in ListTile

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I am writing a small application in Dart/Flutter with ListView (that shows data - text, and images - from the Internet). I have two problems two solve in this code.

Here is my code (the part that shows data in ListView):

```
  ListView _testsListView(data) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return _tile(data[index].title, data[index].lead, data[index].href, data[index].imageHref);
        });
  }

  ListTile _tile(String title, String lead, String href, String imageHref) => ListTile(

    subtitle: Text(lead,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          fontSize: 12,
          color: Colors.green,
        )),
    title: Text(title,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
    ),
    leading: CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: imageHref,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
    ),
  );
}

void launchWeb(String URL) async
{
    if (await canLaunch(URL)) {
      await launch(URL);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $URL';
    }
}
```

The first problem is I need clickable element, one element of ListView:

title (**title** here),

subtitile (**lead** in my code),

leading (image with **imageHref**),

...needs to be clickable. When the user clicks it should open a website (in a default web browser) where URL is href. I tried random codes from Internet and tried with flutter_linkify and url_launcher, but it does not work.
On the other hand, when I use onTap: application automatically (without pressing anything) opens web page, which is of course not desired here.

The second problem is that I need images in ListView (the leading property). Images I wanted to use from some website which address starts with htpps:// and I got "handshake" error:

```
(2) Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════
Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
    CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:354))
```

I used the Image.network(), but it did not work (I have read that this method changes user agent), so I decided to use CachedNetworkImage, but still have problems to view those images. URLs of images are correct and when I use them from the Chrome browser there are no problems with viewing images.

Comment: `On the other hand, when I use onTap: application automatically (without pressing anything) opens web page, which is of course not desired here.` Can you show how you used `onTap`?

Comment: I use - as I remember - that way: onTap: launchWeb(href);

Comment: use it this way: `onTap: ()=>launchWeb(href)`. The reason it opens WebView without clicking is you are calling the function while assigning.

Comment: OK, Lambda expression. I see now my error. Thanks.

Comment: I can use onTap only with the whole ListTile, but how to use it with one element: title, subtitle or leading?

Comment: Wrap them individually with `Inkwell` like the below answer suggests

Answer (score 0):

```
   return ListTile(
            onTap:(){
            //list tile tap
              }
             ),
             title: InkWell(
                 child: Text('Title'),
                 onTap:(){
               //title tap
                 }
             ),
             subtitle:InkWell(
                 child: Text('Sub Title'),onTap:(){
               //sub title tap
                 }
             ),),
             leading:InkWell(
                 onTap:(){
                 //title tap
                  }
                 ),
                 child: CachedNetworkImage(
                      imageUrl: imageHref,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                    ),
                  )
                )
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Got error: "child parameter is not defined"

Comment: You can find the line where you are getting error ! What u have tried ?? Post code !

Comment: I pasted your code into my ListTitle definition, and error shows on the first occurrence of "child" word.

Comment: Change the url and try and also try changing the widget of cached network image to other network image !

Comment: I will follow your recommendations.